# Reaction Mechanisms: Free Radical Halogenation

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, radicals, halogenation

In Free Radical halogenation using chlorine and sunlight, why does the chlorine-free radical get attached to the allylic carbon?

Will it be correct to say that it follows the anti-Markovnikov rule?

But if so, there is no $\ce{H2O2}$ present...

The substrate can be considered as but-2-ene.

Comment: What's the substrate for free radical halogenation?

Comment: @zenix but-2-ene

Comment: This is not $\ce{HX}$ addition to an alkene. Therefore, Markovnikov rule does not apply here. You should change your question accordingly.

Comment: More specifically, this is not HBr addition in the presence of peroxide (Kharasch reaction). HCl and HI do not work in the Kharasch reaction.

Answer (score 1):

H. C. Brown has suggested that the halogen atom does add but, at high temperatures, is expelled before the second step of free radical addition can occur$^1$.

[image]

Addition of halogen atom gives this radical, which falls apart to regenerate the starting material if the temperature is high or if it does not soon encounter a halogen molecule to complete the addition. Hence, low concentration of halogen can be used with high temperature to favour substitution over addition$^1$.

The allylic radical, on the other hand, once formed, has little option but to wait for a halogen molecule, however low the halogen concentration$^1$.

[image]

For the formation of minor product you may look into [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/140381/major-product-from-allylic-halogenation-of-alkenes?noredirect=1#comment278266_140381) question.

To follow the Markovnikov's or anti-Markovnikov's rule, there should be difference of  electronegativity between the two atoms. Therefore, I do not understand what you are trying to ask.

**Reference**

1. Organic Chemistry- Morrison and Boyd (6E); Page 389-390

Comment: The first step of the allylic mechanism should have the half arrow going to the chlorine radical.

Comment: I would appreciate a reference to H. C. Brown's suggestion.

Comment: @Zhe It's done now. Can you please verify the linked question?

Comment: @Apurvium Sorry, but I don't see a fix, and the linked question has the same problem. The product from step 1 does not correspond with the arrows (the product based on arrows are the allylic radical, hydrogen radical, and chlorine radical, with no new bond formed between chlorine and hydrogen).